# What is the /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/ equivilent in PSQL-12?

Tags: postgresql, wal, incremental-build

I'm working on setting up point in time backups for a PSQL server that I have running, and I'm following a tutorial for an earlier version. I'm trying to figure out what the specific directory is for the DB cluster in PSQL-12 so that I can clear out that directory and test what I've setup. In the video, he runs a recursive remove on the PSQL-10 directory `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main`, and is still able to start the PSQL-10 service again when he's finished the restoration.

When I attempted it, I ran the recursive remove on the directory `/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/` because the command `SHOW data_directory;` told me that is where my server's cluster data is stored. Removing all the data, however, messes up the `postgresql-12.service`, so I can't start it back up when I've completed the recovery.

This is displayed when I restore the backup and run `systemctl start postgresql-12.service`:
`Process: 26672 ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-12/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

`Dec 31 11:07:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 12 data....`

I've tried making a backup of the working /data/ directory and doing a `diff -qr` to see what files differ between the working backup and the point in time backup, but coping those files from the working directory to the PIT directory doesn't seem to fix the issue, and I'm still unable to start the `postgresql-12.service`. It seems, however, that I am able to start the service back up successfully if I just do a mass copy of the working directory to `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main`.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I've done plenty of research trying to find the working cluster directory so I can just erase table information and work on a PIT recovery without messing up the core application prereqs (such as the service), but I can't seem to find the information I'm looking for. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Additionally, if there's a way to spot this directory more quickly in the future, either by a command or looking at the files within, I would love to know so I can implement this procedure on different PSQL versions. Thank you!